# SwiftUI Tab Bar Item Duplicating

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

This is weird, I have a tab bar with 4 defined tabs and the last item is duplicating itself.

```
TabView {
    HomeView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Home", systemImage: "chart.bar.fill")
        }
    GroupsView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Groups", systemImage: "person.3.fill")
        }
    FriendsView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Friends", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.plus")
        }
    ProfileView()
        .tabItem {
            Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
        }
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Happens on both simulator and physical device. Also only seems to be the profile tab, if I move another tab to the end the profile tab duplicates itself but in the middle. Would the view have anything to do with it?

Comment: Replace everyview with an EmptyView() one by one to diagnose.

Comment: Could not replicate your issue in my tests.
 All works well for me, on MacOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3 beta, tested on real ios 16.3 devices, and macCatalyst.
 It could be due to other code you are not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the Views inside `FriendsView` inside of another `View` such as a `Group` or `VStack`.

If you look carefully each tab has a different part of the friends view you have to put them together.

Comment: This solved it for me, too. Weird but the child view in the each tab needed to be wrapped in a VStack

Comment: Fascinating! I had this problem, too. Xcode 15.2 on macOS 14.3.1. Putting the two Text views I had on the child view (one of it had a """ type multiline string literal) solved it for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to **embed** my children **into NavigationStack** swiftUI component which solde the problem.